# Is any alternative option for ui-view in angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Looking for alternative method for page route in angular + spring boot project. With ui-view method page content not visible in page source.

Comment: The given information is not clear and good enough to be answered. Kindly explain your actual requirement in little detail.

Comment: It's solve but there is new problem if you could please help "In my spring boot project with href redirection not working. If you click on href, URL change but it's not redirect. If I try with copy the URL and paste it in search box and press enter then URL redirect to their page."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.